# Formatear tiempo restante java

Tags: java

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo funcionando lo que quiero es que muestre el mensaje en plural o singular dependiendo del tiempo que falte.
En mi codigo al iniciar sesion se inserta en la base de datos el tiempo actual mas el configurado por mi en milisegundos
Luego cada vez q inicia sesion comprueba cuanto tiempo queda para que se vuelva a insertar el tiempo actual mas la configuracion
Entonces muestro un mensaje con el tiempo que dalta para que se vuelva a obtener una recompensa en este caso..

```
String var = usuario.getvariable("tiempodereuso");
long ahora = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long reuso = Long.parseLong(var);
long horas = (reuso - ahora)/ 3600000;
long minutos = (reuso - ahora)/ 60000;
long segundos = (reuso - ahora)/ 1000;
if(var != null && reuso > System.currentTimeMillis())
{
usuario.sendmessage("usuario, obtienes premio 
nuevamente dentro de " + (int)horas + " horas.");
} else {
// Inserto codigo nuevo
}
```

Como hago por ejemplo si queda 1 hora para q envie un mensaje pero diga hora en singular lo mismo con los minutos o segundos

Gracias espero q se entienda el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un ternario por ejemplo:

```
String hourDescr= (hour > 1) ? "horas" : "hora";
```

Ahí `hourDescr` será `horas` cuando `hour` sea mayor a `1`, de lo contrario será `hora`.

Ejemplos de uso:

```
    int hour=10;
    String hourDescr= (hour > 1) ? "horas" : "hora";
    System.out.printf("Dentro de %d %s", hour,hourDescr);
```

**Salida:**

```
Dentro de 10 horas
```

---

```
    int hour=1;
    String hourDescr= (hour > 1) ? "horas" : "hora";
    System.out.printf("Dentro de %d %s", hour,hourDescr);
```

**Salida:**

```
Dentro de 1 hora
```

Comment: Hola gracias lo estaba haciendo de otra manera pero veo mas optima tu forma gracias